# Python server Android client

Tags: android, python-2.7, client-server

I want to make simple communication between python server running on a pc and android client. I tested it with python client program and it worked well but in android it's not working .Here is my python server side code:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '192.168.1.102'
PORT = 8888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'socket created'

#Bind socket to Host and Port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print 'Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Bind Success!'


#listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket is now listening'


while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    print buf
s.close()
```

This is my MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.example.tjsiledar.sendmessage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new SendMessage().execute(editText.getText().toString());
                editText.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my SendMessage.java code :

```
package com.example.tjsiledar.sendmessage;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            try {


                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.102",8888);
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                socket.getOutputStream()));
                outToServer.print(params[0]);
                outToServer.flush();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is vague. What happens? Any errors? Does the server print anything. It should be easy for you to figure out if it hangs somewhere or what errors happen.

Comment: Nothing happens. No errors. I dont get any message on the server side on my pc

Comment: So you never reach `print 'Socket Bind Success!'` which means that `socket.socket()` must be hanging.... but that's unlikely in the extreme. Has your server been severely compromised?

Comment: No I meant when I type the message in android and send it by clicking the button I dont receive it on the python server side. The python server side is running perfect. On the server side it reaches till "Socket is now listening" and waits. On the android side it also executes this line `editText.getText().clear();`, but still nothing is received on the server side.

Comment: I'm not a java expert and won't be much good spotting java specific errors. But it would be interesting to have traces in `protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {` especially in the general exception handler ` catch (Exception e)`. The code does something  and figuring that something out will hint at the problem.

Comment: Indeed. Put Log.d() statements in doinBackground to see how the code flows. You better let doZinBackground return a String so you can return different text when things go ok or if there is a catch. Show the string in onPostExecute.

Comment: @greenapps that Log statement helped me in figuring out that I did not give android.permission.INTERNET. Its working now. Thanks both of you for your help :-)